# Authenticated Response From Instagram Internal API C#

Tags: c#, cookies, http-headers, httpwebrequest, instagram

I'm trying to get an authenticated web request from Instagram's Internal API using a cookie with an active sessionid but I'm still ending up on the login screen and I would like it to return the JSON as it does when in a logged-in with a regular browser.

Endpoint: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/*user_id*/info/

...Cookie Setup...

```
 CookieContainer cookiesLocal = new CookieContainer();
 Cookie mycookie = new Cookie();
 mycookie.Name = "sessionid";
 mycookie.Value = "###";
 mycookie.Domain = ".instagram.com";
 mycookie.Secure = true;
 cookiesLocal.Add(mycookie);
```

...Request Headers...

```
 request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
 request.Host = "www.instagram.com";
 request.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken: " + token + "");
 request.KeepAlive = true;
```

Is there anything I'm missing here from the cookie setup?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, for some reason removing the host header seemed to work